# Can anyone help me on why this loop isn't working?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am taking a value from a textbox and I want to ad all the integers below that value until you hit it. For example, if someone entered 3, I would want to add 3+2+1 then display that output.

```js
function number4() {
  box4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= box4; i++) {
    total += i;
  };
  alert(box4);
}
```

```html
TYPE A NUMBER IN INPUT BOX: <input id='box4'>
<button onclick='number4()'>Alert sum of all integers from zero to box value
```

Comment: what is the value of `box4` before the loop

Comment: @JaromandaX someone enters the value, a textbox will come up and you enter the value.

Comment: Yes, OK ... so what does your function do now? what does the alert show

Comment: You should `alert(total)`, not `alert(box4)`

Comment: @JaromandaX The alert should show the ending value. So if someone entered a 3, the alert should show a 6 (3+2+1+0).

Comment: @Barmar - I was trying to teach OP to fish, rather than hand him the fish :p

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! That was it! Such a little simple thing makes all the difference!

Comment: @JaromandaX He was never going to see it, it's just a typo.

Comment: @Barmar - I guess so - my next question was going to be "and which variable holds that total" :p

Comment: `box4` is a String. `let box4 = +document.getElementById('box4').value` to cast it to a Number.

Answer (score 1):

#### You're getting a string instead of a number

```
box4 = document.getElementById('box4').value; // -> '4'
```

Instead you would want to do this

```
box4 = Number(document.getElementById('box4').value); // -> 4
```

Also, You would want to alert total not box4 because total is the one being updated to have sum.

Box4 is storing the value of the input field.

```
alert(total)
```

Here's the working code:

```js
function number4() {
  const box4 = Number(document.getElementById('box4').value);
  
  let total = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i <= box4; i++) {
    total += i;
  };

  alert(total);
}
```

```html
 TYPE A NUMBER IN INPUT BOX: <input id='box4'>
    <button onclick='number4()'>Alert sum of all integers from zero to box value</button>
```